# Why won't the array pass from this function when called back discord.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, discord, discord.js

I'm not sure why the array that is created in this loop inside an async function doesn't pass through to when I call it back later in the code.

I have made async functions that await reactions work properly, then normal sync functions that ask questions and wait for the reply from the user, but never an async function that awaits a reply and passes a value for use later. So, I'm not certain what I'm missing here. I am fairly new to async functions.

The following function does a few things. It asks the user what card names should be added to the deck they just made (made by another function in the code). When the user provides the list of card names, the code checks each card individually to see if the card exists in the database. If it finds the card, it pushes it to the "matchedcards" array. If the card fails to add, it sends a message to Discord saying it wasn't found.

It DOES add the found cards to the array, because I have it logging to console and it shows the array with the cards I know exist and ignoring the one that failed.

The problem is when I try to use the array that I passed later on in the code, it acts as if the array is empty. I'm not sure why the "matchedcards" value isn't passed properly.

```
async function cardExists() {

let msg = await message.author.send(`Please provide the cardnames that you would like to add to '${userdeckname}'.\n\n**NOTE:** Please separate each card with a comma and space, like so "Pact of Darkness, Aquos Slam, Karmic Balance"`)

const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
const reply = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 })
 .catch(console.error);

let cardsToAdd = reply.first()

let usercardnamearray = cardsToAdd.content.split(", ")

let matchedcards = []

usercardnamearray.forEach(function(element) {
con.query(`SELECT cardname FROM card_info where cardname = '${element}'`, (error, rows) => {

if (rows == [] || rows == ""){
message.author.send(`The card **${element}** could not be added. Please check your spelling, capitalization and enter your list of cards again!`)
} else if (rows[0] != undefined || rows[0] != null || rows[0] != "" || rows[0]){

matchedcards.push(element)
console.log(`'${element}' found in database!`)
console.log(matchedcards)
}
})
})
console.log(matchedcards)
return matchedcards;
}
```

Then this is where I use the code later on... I'm not sure if it is running too early or what

```
(async function(){
//Some other if/else statements, each being determined by different functions stated earlier in the code... code below is inside the if else statement that worked fine until this variable doesn't get passed

let matchedcards = await cardExists();
if (matchedcards.length > 0){
matchedcards.join(", ")
message.author.send(`You have added **${matchedcards}** to ${userdeckname}!`) 
let sql2 = `INSERT INTO devdecks (creatoruser, creatorid, deckname, cardnames) VALUES ('${author.username}', ${author.id}, '${userdeckname}', '${matchedcards}')`
con.query(sql2)
}
```

The function works as intended, like I mentioned, I just get a reply like this instead "You have added ** to Test Deck 21!" to discord instead of the array/list cards that succeeded... I hope I'm not missing something small that I'll facepalm and say I'm stupid over...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How are the `message` and `userdeckname` passed to the `cardExists()` function ?. Could you also give a bit more details on how and when your second block of code is called ?

Comment: @Gruntzy I can provide the entire code file so you can see everything about what is there. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikf7qatj0snruz1/createdeck.js?dl=0

userdeckname is entered by the user before anything becomes async in the code. I tried the same method as asking for the deckname for the list of cards, but because it would be done inside the async section, it wouldn't work. message is created and sent inside cardExists(), so I don't think it would be considered passed to it as it is created in the function. I have a couple previous functions that did it that way and worked fine.

Comment: `let addtodeck = await addToDeckQuestion();` . you are not using the result in you next `if`statement, so my guess is your code supposed to call `cardExists` is never reached

Comment: I fixed that, but the problem hasn't changed... Here's how that code looks when run... In Discord: https://i.gyazo.com/1860f6383f7d04d658b3f085260a0961.png
details in the console. https://i.gyazo.com/a72b74f7a95cbc87c0535b0d6a572279.png

I KNOW the array matchedcards gets generated inside the cardExists function, because it says so in the console. It just doesn't get passed out of the function and into use with the if statement directly below await let matchedcards = await cardExists();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from @slothiful's comments and answer, I did a lot of testing with different things. I eventually found out that the query itself was causing issues... So I pulled the query out and put it at the top of the code file like so...

```
con.query(`SELECT cardname FROM card_info`, (error, rows, fields) =>{ 

            let cardsList = []
            for (var i in rows) {
                cardsList.push(rows[i].cardname)
            }
            console.log(cardsList)
```

This made a large array of every card name in the table. This would also allow me to use .indexOf later on, just to see if the card name proposed exists...

The final function was as follows...

```
async function cardExists() {

let msg = await message.author.send(`Please provide the cardnames that you would like to add to '${userdeckname}'.\n\n**NOTE:** Please separate each card with a comma and space, like so "Pact of Darkness, Aquos Slam, Karmic Balance"`)

const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
const reply = await msg.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1 })
.catch(console.error);

let cardsToAdd = await reply.first()

let usercardnamearray = await cardsToAdd.content.split(", ")

let matchedcards = []
let unmatchedcards = []

for (let i = 0; i < usercardnamearray.length; i++) {

let found = cardsList.indexOf(`${usercardnamearray[i]}`)
console.log(found)

if (found >= 0) {
matchedcards.push(usercardnamearray[i])
} else if (found == -1){
unmatchedcards.push(usercardnamearray[i])
}     
}
console.log('Finished!')
return await [matchedcards, unmatchedcards]
}
```

And now the values for matchedcards and unmatchedcards finally got passed to the callback later.

```
let cards = await cardExists();  
let matchedcards = await cards[0]
let unmatchedcards = await cards[1]

message.author.send(await `You have added **${matchedcards.join(", ")}** to ${userdeckname}!`) 
message.author.send(await `The card **${unmatchedcards.join(", ")}** could **NOT** be added. Please check your spelling, capitalization and enter your list of cards again!`)
let sql2 = await `INSERT INTO devdecks (creatoruser, creatorid, deckname, cardnames) VALUES ('${author.username}', ${author.id}, '${userdeckname}', '${matchedcards.join(", ")}')`
await con.query(sql2)
}
```

I don't know if this is essentially an answer so much as it is a work around to get what I needed... I do wish I knew why the query inside the loop in an async function caused matchedcards and unmatchedcards to pass too early. Maybe queries are synchronous? That would be news to me, but I might have just had a combo that didn't work well while a loop, a query and an if/else statement together causes issues. I don't know, but I got it working! Thanks again to @slothiful for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is built, it doesn't care about returned values. It simply executes the code and moves on, *without waiting for your callback to be completed*. Therefore, your function keeps going and returns the array before values can be inserted into it.

My suggestion is to use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), as demonstrated below. As opposed to `forEach()`, it'll have the patience to wait for your code and give you the intended results.

```js
const arr = [5, 10, 15];

console.log(`BEFORE: ${arr.join(', ')}`);

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(`CHANGING: ${arr[i]}`);

  arr[i]++;
}

console.log(`AFTER: ${arr.join(', ')}`);
```

Comment: I think I changed it up properly, adding in passing a second variable too, but I'm getting the same results... Here's some screenshots

Of the code: https://i.gyazo.com/78fb4fbc16caa7938765eff15e640f62.png
The callback later: https://i.gyazo.com/6f12778cdc5f91914496df1aca14f205.png
what gets put to console: https://i.gyazo.com/4282dca64ff8e675dae934b2f7d44bfc.png
And what gets sent to Discord: https://i.gyazo.com/e7fd8b2626742d5ead24e6a307840157.png
I might have just missed something though. Thanks for toughing through it with me though.

Comment: You should be returning the arrays *outside* of the `for` loop.

Comment: I thought I was... The } right above the return line is paired with the bracket starting the for loop statement. The little grey boxes on the brackets tell me that at least... https://i.gyazo.com/3471f967a40a1b5d74c5075ed2d18b55.png Am I missing something maybe? Idk anymore. lol

Comment: Ah, sorry. The indentation threw me off. Put `await` before your query call. You'll have to make your function async.

Comment: No change to the result... I put await right before "con.query". No change to the result, unfortunately. I hadn't even considered putting "await" before the query call though. Any other ideas to try?

Comment: Log each step to the console to try to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: All the logged results from inside the cardExists function looks to be exactly what I expect. However, I seem to get empty arrays when logging cards, matchedcards and unmatched cards in the callback. Those results also appear before the logged results from the function. It is like it doesn't wait for the function to run despite being async and using await cardExists?? First 5 lines are what I am fairly certain is being logged inside the callback. The last 8 lines come from the function itself and look exactly right. https://i.gyazo.com/30b0c73f7397808341c7ecc69f799691.png